# OneHotEncoding issue with unseen data on test set

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, one-hot-encoding

I have data with numerical and categorical variables. I have split the data into train and test. I would like to do one hot encoding after imputation. There are unseen data on the test set.

I understand `handle_unknown='ignore'` fixes this issue. However, I would also like to drop one column (`drop='first'`) to avoid multicollinearity. OnehotEncoding cannot take both of these.

Is there a way to handle the unseen data and also avoid multicollinearity?

Note: I am using ColumnTransformer.

Comment: The error that gets raised when trying to set both brings up a good point:
 "`handle_unknown` must be 'error' when the drop parameter is specified, as both would create categories that are all zero."
That is, the end behavior if you could use both of these options would be that unseen levels in the test set will be treated exactly the same as the dropped level.  However, I don't see an easy way to do that if you're fine with that effect, without a custom transformer somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

You'd better use array slicing and design a custom transformer so that you still can apply such transformer within your `ColumnTransformer`. [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-columntransformer-to-combine-data-processing-steps-af383f7d5260) you will find an example of how you can create a custom transformer.